# AC voltage and frequency measurement

Tags: ac, three-phase

I am planning to measure the AC voltage from a 3-Phase ranging 480V/690V effective value with almost 10-20% tolerance => a max. peak of around 1171V.

I try to use protective impedance to step down the voltage to 2,5V and biasing the 2,5V with a voltage divider as you can see on the picture below.

I was expecting to have at U1 voltage shift from -2,5V to 0V and from 2,5V to 5V, but I am getting voltage shifted to 1,26V and 3,74V. Could some help to explain? The idea is to shift U1 to 2,5V and leave room for overvoltage and undervoltage, if this occurs. Other voltage are just to understand different impact on the voltage to be measured.

This voltage would be send to an ADC in µC, to measure the AC-voltage.

How can I also measure the frequency through this step down voltage? How can I detect zero crossing?

[image]

Comment: Where are the three sources referenced to?

Comment: the 3-phase does not have any reference on the circuit or the reference point is the joining point of the 3-phases.

Comment: I am arguing about the voltage U1 on the phase with 120V phase shift. as I would like to set the voltage with bias to 2,5V and I will be having margin for under- and overvoltage.

Comment: In real application the reference point is the neutral. So your DC reference point (GND) should be tied to the neutral or else you'll get random results since the parasitic capacitances will be more effective. Tie the common junction point in your simulation to GND and re-take the measurements.

Comment: Safety ... Remember that "some" resistors does not "allow" a high voltage (150 V ?) ... So use the "right" number of serial resistors ... You can also use "high voltage" rated resistors. Be aware of the parasitics capacitors ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is just about the simplest circuit possible to read one phase line-to-neutral having a peak amplitude of 690V (488V RMS) nominal to 1171V (828V RMS) maximum, using a 5V ADC.

[image: 480V L-N measurement]

Zero crossings can be detected by sampling in software, and frequency will just be based on the period as measured between zero crossings.

(edit) For just peak voltage measurement, use the ratio of 690/(3.877-2.5) = 501V/V. This is the ratio of the three 499k series resistors to the two 6.02k resistors in parallel. Assuming a 10 bit 5V ADC, an input sample of 3.877V would be 794 counts. The ADC will read 501*5/1024 = 2.44 V/count. Subtract 512 counts for the offset to get 282 counts, multiply by 2.44, and you have your 690V.

If you want to get a true-RMS reading, you will need to take perhaps 16 samples per cycle, square them, total the readings, and divide by 16 (shift right 4). Then take the square root. It is important to sample over a single cycle (or integral number of half-cycles) to get a consistent and accurate reading.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply with simulation. Could you please also provide a set form how to calculate the voltage at the out point? Taking in consideration the voltage 690V, I am having the sum of 2,76V for the voltage divider and 2,5V for bias, resulting in 5,26V. Base on simulation, it is 3,88V.

Comment: For just peak voltage measurement, use the ratio of 690/(3.877-2.5) = 501V/V. This is the ratio of the three 499k series resistors to the two 6.02k resistors in parallel. Assuming a 10 bit 5V ADC, an input sample of 3.877V would be 794 counts. The ADC will read 501*5/1024 = 2.44 V/count.  Subtract 512 counts for the offset to get 282 counts, multiply by 2.44, and you have your 690V.